# How to override NSObject's default comparison in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsobject

I have a custom class `Player` that conforms to `NSObject, NSCoding`. A `Player` object is instantiated with a `id: String!`

One of the issues I am encountering is when I perform an operation like the following:

```
let listOfPlayers = [Player]()
//populate listOfPlayers
if listOfPlayers.contains(aPlayer) ...
```

Specifically, the `contains` would return results based on the memory pointer, and not based on the `id` value. As such, I would get a `true` in some cases and `false` in others.

I would like to override the default comparison methods, and did the following:

```
func isEqual(object: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    if let otherPlayer = object as? Player {
        return self.id == otherPlayer.id
    }
    return false
}


static func == (lhs: Player, rhs: Player) -> Bool {
    return lhs.id == rhs.id
}
```

However, these functions are not being executed. I have also tried to add `override`, but it returns an error "Method does not override any method from its superclass`

What is the right way to have a customer comparator so it is only comparing the `id` element?

Thanks!

Comment: When you wrote `isEqual` and the compiler didn't make you insert `override`, that was a clue!

Comment: Could you explain what the downvote is for?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of Swift 3, the `isEqual` method of `NSObject` takes an `Any?`
parameter, so you are not overriding the correct method, that's 
why it is never called.

You should also override `var hash: Int` (equal objects *must* have the same hash) – otherwise the object will behave wrongly in hashable collections (sets, dictionaries):

```
class Player: NSObject {
    let id: String

    init(id: String) { self.id = id }

    override func isEqual(_ object: Any?) -> Bool {
        if let other = object as? Player {
            return self.id == other.id
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }

    override var hash: Int {
        return id.hashValue
    }
}
```

Some tests:

```
let p1 = Player(id: "a")
let p2 = Player(id: "a")

print(p1 == p2) // true
print(p1 != p2) // false

// Native Swift set:
let set = Set([Player(id: "x"), Player(id: "y"), Player(id: "z")])
print(set.contains(Player(id: "y"))) // true

// Foundation set:
let nsset = NSSet(objects: Player(id: "x"), Player(id: "y"), Player(id: "z"))
print(nsset.contains(Player(id: "y"))) // true
```

Comment: I'm drinking the koolaid again... `return (object as? Player).map { $0.id == other.id } ?? false`

Comment: @Alexander: Your submission to the IOSCC (international obfuscated Swift code contest) ? 

Comment: Heh it certainly could be! It's a shame more people don't know about the `map` and `flapMap` on Optional. It allows for some really nice syntax

Answer (score 0):

I threw the following code into a playground.

```
class Player : NSObject {
    var id : String = ""

    static func == (lhs: Player, rhs: Player) -> Bool {
        print("We checked here")
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}

//Direct comparison will call our function.
if Player() == Player() {
    print("yay")
}

let players : [Player] = [Player()]

//Even though Player() has same id, it is new object in memory so this won't evaluate as true when comparing with `contains()`, 
//hence why "we checked here" isn't called again.
if players.contains(Player()) {
    print("Dang we suck")
}

//Could check with something like this if you want to check your array for a particular id.
if players.contains(where: {$0.id == Player().id }) {
    print("Im awesome")
}
```

Output:

```
We checked here
yay
Im awesome
```

I believe `[NSObject].contains()` uses the triple equal's comparison `===` as opposed to direct equals comparison which will check to see if it is same object in memory, as opposed to a particular `id`. As you can see `We checked here` is only called with direct comparison. You can use the `contains(where: predicate)` method to get a particular condition.

Comment: `NSObject`'s `!=` and `==` call to `isEqual`. To properly define equality for an `NSObject` subclass, you need to override `isEqual`.

Comment: http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/59c2bd5b052a1b77c5e05898 Have to specifically override the `!=` operator as well or else it will go bak to default implementation, which checks memory address.

Comment: @NSGanster Yeah, but there's no point. If you just override `isEqual`, then both `==` and `!=` would work properly (since they both delegate to `isEqual`), *and* your class would behave as expected in ObjC code, too